# JdbcTemplate SQL Server (spring)

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-security, jdbctemplate

We use Spring boot, spring secuity 5.0.4 (JdbcUserDetailsManager), SQL Server 2017. We got serious exception:

> bad SQL grammar [insert into authorities (username, authority) values (?,?)]; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'authorities'.

It looks like, that native SQL query (bellow) doesn't contain [dbo].[dbName].authorities  .

`public static final String | DEF_INSERT_AUTHORITY_SQL | "insert into authorities (username, authority) values (?,?)"`

Configuration
Spring security core 5.0.4
MS SQL Server 2017
Hibernate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

How to fix it?

Comment: That error message shows the SQL statement as seen by SQL Server, and SQL Server doesn't understand the `?` parameter markers, as that is a JDBC concept. It means the SQL statement is executed wrong. Don't know what that line with `|` in it is, because it's not Java. In case that was supposed to define a constant named `DEF_INSERT_AUTHORITY_SQL`, where is that constant used? Show us your code.